# How to get correct angle of trendline in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, degrees

I am using excel SLOPE and ANGLE function to calculate the angle of trendline given the data points. But it always shows very high angle (~88 degrees). And if I change my x axis coordinates to same as y axis , then it shows 45 degrees at maximum, irrespective of how steep the slope is.

But actual angle of trendline is somewhat near 26 degrees for the following data points, whereas excel shows it 88 degrees.

```
week  price
1     5521.41
2     5579.73
3     5639.15
```

EXCEL formula used : =DEGREES(ATAN(SLOPE(y axis range, x axis range)))
[image]

Actual trendline of these data points in action and actual degrees

[image]

Comment: Well actual "angle" is ~89 degrees if x:y ratio is 1:1. Change y axis bounds to 5500-5700 and you will have somewhere near your wanted 26 degrees result. Change to 5000-6000 and you will have different result.

Comment: Do not draw the Week column this is the x coord.

Comment: The slope of the trendline is not the angle you see on the screen, unless your x-axis and y-axis have the exact same scales. In your example, the price goes up by about 60 units when the week number goes up by 1 unit, so that would be a very steep slope. As @user11222393 said, the angle on the screen changes depending on your bounds, so it is not a useful measure.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So is there anyway to get the right angle using formula, otherwise I need to see the price graph on tradingview and draw the angle manually which gives ~26.